# What value of k makes function continuous

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I realise that you cannot just plug in zero and set both functions to equal each other because of dividing by zero, but how should I proceed to find k? Am I allowed to plug in two different values of x, one for each function?

[image]

Comment: What is the limit of $\frac{\sin(-6x)}{9x}$ as $x$ goes to $0$?

Comment: Use L'hospital rule to calculate left hand side limit and for right hand side just plug 0.

Comment: @kingW3 -6/9 I think. Rusty at this.

Comment: Yeah, so $-6/9=-9k-6$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*HINT*

The condition that must be satisfied is $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}\frac{\sin(-6x)}{9x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}(3x-9k-6)$$

But the second branch is equal to $-9k-6$ if we plug in the value $0$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: @MathmaticianByMistak So you mean I can plug in a value slightly smaller than zero on one side, and a value slightly larger than zero for the other

Comment: @jerweb63 No, I mean that you can plug in zero on the second branch because it is *defined* at zero $(\ge 0)$ but you must calculate the *limit* as $x$ tends towards zero from the left side, hence the $0^{-}$. Can you calculate that limit?

Comment: @MathmaticianByMistak I believe the limit is as x approaches zero from the right is -6.

Comment: @jerweb63 Hmm..Let's see. We have $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}\frac{\sin(-6x)}{9x}=-\frac69\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}\frac{\sin(-6x)}{-6x}=-\frac69\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin u}{u}$ but we also know that $\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin u}{u}=1$. So?